# Django QuerySet not appearing in HTML file for PythonAnywhere Web App

Tags: python, html, django, sqlite

I'm having a bit of trouble with [this part](https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/django_templates/) of the DjangoGirls tutorial (about templates).

Currently, my website is at [chocoberrie.pythonanywhere.com](http://chocoberrie.pythonanywhere.com). It's supposed to show a few posts inside the QuerySet, but the list is empty, and I don't know why (or how to fix it).

**1) The QuerySet isn't loading at all in the HTML file.**

I followed the steps to import the Post model into views.py and add the QuerySet in the posts variable (the [previous part](https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/dynamic_data_in_templates/) of the tutorial). When I tried putting {{ posts }} in the HTML file (post_list.html), nothing appears in the QuerySet that loads on the page.

**2) I don't know how to edit the database file on PythonAnywhere.** This database file is supposed to be separate from the local db.sqlite3 on my computer (since db.sqlite3 is in the .gitignore file, it's not committed).

I read about this [here](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/5662/). I understand that this is useful to keep production changes from being displayed on the live website, but how I supposed to have this data on the PythonAnywhere side? What file am I supposed to edit on PythonAnywhere?

Thanks for the help, I appreciate it!

---

Here are my local files:

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.post_list, name='post_list'),
]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.utils import timezone
from .models import Post

def post_list(request):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('published_date')
    return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {'posts': posts})
```

**post_list.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Dina's blog</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <h1><a href="/">Dina's Blog</a></h1>
    </div>

    {{ posts }}

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: my guess is you just haven't created any posts in the pythonanywhere version of your site yet?  go to to chocoberrie.pythonanywhere.com/admin and create some?

Comment: @hwjp Yes, that was the issue! Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

you cant just use the query_list like that in the template, you need to loop through it in the template and it will show all posts titles so your template will be like this

```
{% for post in posts %}
<p>{{post.post_title}}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

i recommend following this [blog](http://setthecode.pythonanywhere.com/)

Comment: I tried that as well, but the page is now completely empty.

Comment: I have a list of querysets, because I made an empty list variable and added querysets to it in a for loop, but it's not displaying when I have them in a list.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if you have already done it or not, but when actually creating the posts you will also have to save it. So for example:

Example form.py

```
from django import forms

class createPostForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(required = True)
    detail = forms.CharField(required = True)
```

Example views.py

```
import models

def createPost(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            title = form.cleaned_data.get('title')
            detail = form.cleaned_data.get('detail')

            newPost = models.Post(title = title, detail = detail)
            newPost.save()
            return redirect('blog/post_list.html')
```

Otherwise you won't be able to access it, since your website will take the inputs in and it will look like a post was created if the fields were valid, but your posts won't actually get created and your database will be empty! Also get a database viewer so that you can see if the entries are actually there.

Comment: first ask him if he did that or not in comments, then this not the problem

Comment: Have you seen that the QuerySet is empty?? If the OP is not saving the post then how on earth is a for loop going to work?

Comment: Although to show the posts they would actually have to do the for loop that you did. But is there any error handling necessary if the QuerySet is empty? So for example, if they indeed forgot to save the objects?

Comment: @moonyWolf I see what you mean, but I'm a complete beginner here. The tutorial I'm using doesn't do what you suggested, and I'm not sure how to do it on my own.

Comment: @Dee this seems like a good tutorial to follow along. http://www.pythoncentral.io/writing-your-first-python-django-application/
You have already had some knowledge from the tutorial you were following, now just look how they are doing it in terms of the code and the structure.

Comment: @moonyWolf Thanks for the tutorial recommendation! I'll definitely take a look. What do you think of my issue though? Is it solvable?

Comment: https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/django_orm/
On this page, you will see that they went into the interactive shell and manually created Posts. They also executed a command `Post.objects.all()` which did NOT return an empty QuerySet. So check first if you can get a similar result.
Right after that command they also show how to create a Post object. Make sure, you have followed it entirely. If it returns empty QuerySet then create posts through the Shell in a similar way. And you should be good.